# How to restart coredns pod without downtime in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, ttl, coredns

I have a coredns pod running in kube-system namespace. I need to restart the coredns pod without downtime. I am aware that we can do delete coredns pod using below command and new coredns pod will spin up automatically.
`kubectl delete pods -n kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns`

But it is creating downtime. So I am expecting to do a restart of this coredns pod without downtime.

It would be really helpful when someone helps me on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: wondering, are you not having replicas for that pod running to failover ?

Comment: Same here, scale the coredns deployment to more than one pod, and then you can delete the old pod instance and scale down....but you should have more than 1 replica 

Comment: @Hackerman  As I am quite new to this containerization, can you show an example how we can modify coredns deployment to have replica more than 1?

Comment: `kubectl scale --help` is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the result of this command `kubectl get deployment coredns --namespace kube-system --output jsonpath='{.spec.strategy.rollingUpdate.maxUnavailable}'` will return 1; means for deployment of 2 pods (typical coredns setup), pod will be replace 1 at a time, leaving the other one serving request. In this case, you can run `kubectl rollout restart deployment coredns --namespace kube-system` to restart without downtime, no explicitly delete or hike coredns pod count required.

Comment: So typical coredns setup you mean is to have two coredns pods in one worker node by having relpica count 2?

Comment: `replicas` of 2 is typical. `rollout restart` works on single or more nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to restart coredns? If you need to reload coredns configmap, the best practice is to reload coredns when configmap is changed.

> The coredns will reload itself after a period of 30 to 45 secs as you have specified the 'reload' configuration in the configMap. https://coredns.io/plugins/reload/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75757002/6059840

Comment: If you think another question Stack Overflow answers this one as well, don't just post a link to that answer (never post link-only answers at all actually). Instead, [flag it as a duplicate](/help/duplicates), thus associating this question with the target, keeping knowledge centralised.